# How to set the default host when using Rubber to deploy to EC2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, deployment

I am running Rails 3.0.3 and trying to use Rubber to deploy my app to Amazon ec2. I watched Railscast #347 on this subject and followed every step. But when I run `cap rubber:create_staging`, I get `.../gems/amazon-ec2-0.9.17/lib/AWS.rb:142:in 'initialize': No :server provided (AWS::ArgumentError)`, which when I look at the line in AWS.rb seems like I should have set a default_host somewhere, but Ryan Bates never mentioned that in the Railscast and I don't know where to set that or what that even really means in this context. In which config file can I set the default host? Or is this indicative of a different problem? Thanks so much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You're running a really old version of Rubber.  Please try upgrading to the latest 2.x release and let me know if that works.